# How do I get the attention of the people who have commented on my question?

Tags: support

I have posted a question that received a couple of comments that asked me to add a copy of my code into the post.  I have done that, and I would like to get the attention of those two people who made that comment.  How do I do that?

Would it be ok for me to repost my question so that it would get the attention of those people and others?

Comment: To future voters:  the premise of the question is perfectly fine.  There's nothing wrong with what they're asking.  You may disagree with what they were initially thinking, but don't let what they were thinking detract from an otherwise routine question 'round these parts.

Comment: @Makoto Perhaps they were downvoting for "lack of research" precisely because this question is so routine?

Comment: @Makoto and Mike McCaughan I don't understand what you two are talking about.  for one, what are who voting for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reposting your question wouldn't be the right way to do this.  Instead, comment *below* their comments and ping one of them using `@username`, substituting "username" for their display name.

Comment: @Makato Thank you.  That's what I need to know.  I didn't know how to "ping" people.